# Rendering a block in extended -> included template

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-extension

**Problem**

In `navbar.html.twig` I have a block that looks like this:

```
//navbar.html.twig
{% block back_link %}{% endblock %}
```

This navbar is `include`d by my `base.html.twig`.

```
//base.html.twig
{% include navbar.html.twig %}
```

And then my page template `extend`s the base.

```
//page.html.twig
{% extends base.html.twig %}

...

{% block back_link %} Things i want in the navbar. {% endblock %}
```

But the things I want in the navbar don't show up in the navbar, because it's `include`d by the base, so there's no parent/child relationship there.

**Question**

What's a good (or any) way to let me override a block in an included template in an extended template?

Comment: Includes can't change blocks from templates which included them

Answer (score 0):

if you understand your idea right, you want to have some reusable content for a navbar, separated to navbar.html.twig that will possible to use in several templates?

So you can do it with "use" http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html

In navbar.html.twig

```
//navbar.html.twig
{% block back_link %}{% endblock %}
```

In base.html.twig.

```
//base.html.twig
{% use '::navbar.html.twig' %}
{{ block('back_link') }}
```

In page.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block back_link %} Things i want in the navbar. {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I tried this, but now it's not rendering the navbar at all. But it is still rendering the `Things i want in the navbar.` where the navbar should be.

Comment: From what you posted "//navbar.html.twig
{% block back_link %}{% endblock %}" your navbar has only the block. So  if you see "Things i want in the navbar." this mean that the block is rendered

Comment: If you need more content you can set this content in new block like navber_conent, and use {{ block('navbar_content') }} that will have back_link inside